# Multiply and add column values

Tags: php, laravel, loops

Working on Laravel and I'm a bit confused with operations. I have 2 columns **count_all** and **price_unit** and I'm trying to multiply their values and then add them together. I'm trying to do so with:

```
@foreach($materials as $material)
    {{$sum += $material->price_unit * $material->count_all}}
@endforeach
```

But it returns error:

```
Undefined variable: sum
```

Comment: Please read Your error and then Your code - it will clarify everything.

Comment: use this: `{% $sum += $material->price_unit * $material->count_all %}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$sum += $material->price_unit * $material->count_all` means `$sum = $sum + $material->price_unit * $material->count_all` . first time in your loop `$sum` is not defined so you have to declare it outside of loop

```
<?php $sum=0; ?>
@foreach($materials as $material)
    {{$sum += $material->price_unit * $material->count_all}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: oh I didn't know about that. Thanks. I will probably write the loop within <? php ?> so I get only final $sum value to show.

Comment: You can define a variable by doing `@php ($sum = 0)` (to my knowledge), no need for the tags.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `@php` instead of `{{}}`

To declare `$sum` (outside the loop) first: `@php($sum = 0)`

Then `@php($sum += $material->price_unit * $material->count_all)`

If you want to print it, use `{{$sum}}`

Comment: It has nothing to do with using `@php`.